# Roxygen2 cannot process files begining with underscore?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have a collection of small functions that I would like to add to an R package. I list all the functions in a single file, preceeded for each by Roxygen2 indications for building the help file (an example below). It all works well. However, I noted that when I rename that file to begin with an underscore (so that it appears first in my list of files), I get the following error message:

```
Updating mypackage documentation
Loading mypackage
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Warning message:
In setup_ns_exports(path, export_all, export_imports) :
  Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace: a, b
```

Here is the content of the only file in the R subfolder:

```
#' @name a
#' @title the a() function does etc.
#' @description etc.
#' @param x a dataframe containing etc.;
#' @param v a vector containing etc..
#' @return a dataframe of the etc.
#' @export a
a <- function(x, v) { return("somevalue") }

#' @name b
#' @title the b() function does etc.  
#' @description etc.
#' @param x a dataframe containing etc.;
#' @param v a vector containing etc..
#' @return a dataframe of the etc.
#' @export b
b <- function(x, v) { return("some other value") }
```

When I remove the underscore, and re-run `devtools::document()` twice, the error message disapear. I put back the underscore and the error is back. When there is no Roxygen2 tags, there are no error and the functions work nice.

Is this a normal behavior? Is there a way around this error or should I just give up the idea of using the underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not (just) `roxygen2`, it's an R thing.

From [*Writing R Extensions*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html), subsection [*1.1.5 Package subdirectories*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories):

> The `R` subdirectory contains R code files, only. The code files to be installed must start with an ASCII (lower or upper case) letter or digit and have one of the extensions `.R`, `.S`, `.q`, `.r`, or `.s`.

Similarly,

> The `man` subdirectory should contain (only) documentation files for the objects in the package in *R documentation* (Rd) format. The documentation filenames must start with an ASCII (lower or upper case) letter or digit and have the extension `.Rd` (the default) or `.rd`.

This generally isn't an issue using `roxygen2`: while it does name the `.Rd` files based on the function names, and R doesn't allow function names (typically) that start with underscore. From the [*R Language Definition*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) subsection [*10.3.2 Identifiers*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Identifiers):

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (‘.’) and the underscore. They must not start with a digit or an underscore, or with a period followed by a digit.

While it is possible to define a function with an identifier that begins with an underscore, it requires wrapping the function name in backticks for definition and any time it is used (since it is not a "valid identifier").

Comment: Then why does the library function when there is no Roxygen2 comments in the file?

Comment: I can't get it to load properly, so I don't know why it appears to work for you.